# How is weak measurement operator formed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-measurements

I am new to the topic of weak measurement. While reading this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.95.110409) ( the open Arxiv version is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0503017) ), the authors have just introduced the operators:
$$\hat{P}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\tanh(x)}{2}}\hat{P1}+\sqrt{\frac{1+ \tanh(x)}{2}}\hat{P2}$$
where $\hat{P}1$ and $\hat{P}2$ are projection operators.

My question is that how did we arrive at the term containing the hyperbolic function. What is so unique about $\sqrt{\frac{1\mp \tanh(x)}{2}}$, and how did the author arrive at it?

Edit:
As the link was not available for everyone, I am adding a bit of context.

The paper wants to give an idea about how every generalized measurement can be implemented as the sequence of weak measurements. Then the author has restricted to two outcome measurements, given by the operator above. $x$ is used to denote the strength of the weak measurement.

Comment: The article you cite is unfortunately behind a paywall, if you could cite part of it (either via text or picture) it would help.

Comment: @ErickShock, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I can't connect to the site with the paper, but I don't think there's much to it. If you have two numbers $\alpha,\beta > 0$ such that $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$, you can always find $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \alpha = \sqrt{\frac{1-\tanh(x)}{2}}, \qquad \beta = \sqrt{\frac{1+\tanh(x)}{2}} $$
The formula for this $x$ is 
$$ x= {\rm artanh}(1-2\alpha^2) = {\rm artanh}(\beta^2-\alpha^2)  =  {\rm artanh}(2\beta^2-1) $$
It can also be noticed that (for example)
$$ \beta^2 - \alpha^2 = \tanh x$$
$$ \frac{1}{\alpha\beta} = \sqrt{\frac{4}{1-\tanh^2x}} = 2\cosh x$$
$$ \frac{1}{\alpha^2} - \frac{1}{\beta^2} = \frac{2}{1-\tanh(x)} - \frac{2}{1+\tanh(x)} = \frac{4\tanh (x)}{1-\tanh^2(x)} = 2\sinh(2x)$$
and some other similar relations, so if these particular combination of parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have some meaning, using parameter $x$ may simplify some formulas.

Comment: Do you mean that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be any other function of x as well? and there is nothing special about this choice.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh As I've said, I couldn't read the the paper so I'm not sure, but I believe $\alpha$ and $\beta$ were just supposed to satisfy the conditiions $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$, $\alpha,\beta>0$. If that's true, you can take any function of $x$ such $f(x):\mathbb R\rightarrow(0,1)$ and define $\alpha =f(x)$, $\beta=\sqrt{1-f(x)^2}$. The authors chose function $f(x)=\sqrt{(1-\tanh x)/2}$ probably only because this choice simplifies some formulas.